# How to use POST method in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Hi all I want to use Rrtrofit to Post parameter. I use GET method in Retrofit and it works perfectly, But now i am unable to use post. Here is my code:

```
public interface Api {

@POST("/Holding")
void getHoldings(@Body String clientCode, Callback<HoldingsResponseParser> holdingsResponseParserCallback);

}
```

My RestClient class :

```
public class RestClient {

private static Api REST_CLIENT;
private static String ROOT =
        "http://mydomain.svc/";

static {
    setupRestClient();
}

private RestClient() {}

public static Api get() {
    return REST_CLIENT;
}

private static void setupRestClient() {
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT)
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

    RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
    REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
 }
}
```

My MainActivity class :

```
RestClient.get().getHoldings("s0002", new Callback<HoldingsResponseParser>() {
        @Override
        public void success(HoldingsResponseParser weatherResponse, Response response) {
            // success!
            System.out.println("Success>>>>>>>>>>");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            // something went wrong
        }
    });
```

After  run application it neither goes in success norin failure method.  Logcat gives me response code:500. In this service I want to pass string in post method.Here in this  code I had passed `s0002`  Ithink I am passing wrongly data in body.

Ant suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: 500 suggests your server is unable to handle the request - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: actually without using Retrofit same service return the response but using Retrofit it gives this error. So I think there  must be some error in my code. Thanks

Comment: Looks ok to me. Are you sure your request does not need any HTTP Headers that make your request works with another client? Also could you give us the output of your error message?

Comment: @ptitvinou  Thanks for suggestion yes you are right after adding GTTP Header it works perfectly. Thanks onece again